MacOS/ARM64 build vite project for Linux/AMD64 stuck
I have a vue.js (3.2) project with vite (5) and vitejsvue plugin (5.0.3). I want to build it in docker on MacOS/ARM64 for Linux/AMD64 server. As shown in the screenshot the build works but it keeps stuck after the transformation. Building on Windows/X86 for Linux works fine as it does on Mac for Mac, because its the same architecture. Any idea on that?


If you are on Apple Silicon, then this answer will most likely solve your issue
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77566452/23571294

Just proving a link is usually not helpful

Thanks, that solved my problem. I mark the question as duplicate.

This just saved me so many hours of debugging!
